# processing.js examples not working

Tags: processing.js

I am looking at the Processing.js quick start examples:
http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html and trying to replicate this "simple" example:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <title>Hello Web - Processing.js Test</title>
   <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/processing-js/processing-js/v1.4.8/processing.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Processing.js Test</h1>
    <p>This is my first Processing.js web-based sketch:</p>
    <canvas data-processing-sources="hello.pde"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what my `hello.pde` file looks like:

```
void setup() {
size(200, 200);
background(100);
stroke(255);
ellipse(50, 50, 25, 25);
println("hello web!");
}
```

Also, I've put both my files, the .pde and the .html ones, into my MAMP server and am accessing them through `localhost`: `http://localhost:8888/testprocessing.html`

But nothing appears on the canvas, and I get this error in the console: 
`processing.js:799 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`. 
This is what the code in processing.js looks like on line 799:

```
function loadBlock(index, filename) {
  function callback(block, error) {
    code[index] = block;
    ++loaded;
    if (error) {
      errors.push(filename + " ==> " + error);
    }
    if (loaded === sourcesCount) {
      if (errors.length === 0) {
        try {
          return new Processing(canvas, code.join("\n"));
        } catch(e) {
          console.log("Processing.js: Unable to execute pjs sketch.");
          throw e; //this is line 799
        }
      } else {
        throw "Processing.js: Unable to load pjs sketch files: " + errors.join("\n");
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm quite new to javascript, and the error is coming from the `processing.js` file, not my code, can anyone explain? Thanks!

Comment: try using the non-minified version and maybe it'll be more descriptive of what the error may be https://cdn.rawgit.com/processing-js/processing-js/v1.4.8/processing.js

Comment: @ClaytonSmith I did what you suggested, and this is what I get...

Comment: @ClaytonSmith actually thanks! From the error in the .js file, I looked back at my .pde file and saw that when I copy-pasted the code, I left the line numbers in.. oups... I erased those and everything works. oups..

Answer (score -1):

You need to rewrite your path to processing library with the full name of the library that you using at the moment.

For example, if you use version 1.4.8 you have to write: `//./././processing-1.4.8.js`